# Develop own android app to Read Values from Smart Band (Health band) with Google Fit API

Tags: android, api, sdk, google-fit

I need to develop an android app which interacts with smartband and retrieve heart beat rate data from band. I wish to implement Google Fit API, could anyone suggest some smart band models which has some sdk or allows our own app with google fit API to communicate with the band.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/fit/) are the current brands that the Google Fit is working with.

So if you are looking for models/brands, just pick one of the mentioned brands. I think that would make sense since they already gave their partnered brands.

To give you an overview about Google fit, here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/overview):

> Google Fit is an open ecosystem that allows developers to upload
>   fitness data to a central repository where users can access their data
>   from different devices and apps in one location:
>
> - Fitness apps can store data from any wearable or sensor.
> - Fitness apps can access data created by any app.
> - User's fitness data is persisted when they upgrade their fitness devices.